# Подсчет уникальных значений

Tags: sql

Есть таблица org (name, emp_id). Для каждого возможного значения `name`, необходимо вывести количество уникальных `emp_id`. Можно ли это сделать с помощью `count()` или как ещё?

**UPD:** Немного расшифрую. Допустим

```
(name)  (emp_id)
apple   85962
apple   14654
intel   14654
intel   14654
```

В результате необходимо получить что-то вроде

```
(name)  count(emp_id)
apple   2
intel   1
```

т.е. если `emp_id` повторяется в разных `name`, то их необходимо подсчитывать

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Первая интерпретация вашего вопроса
Для каждого name подсчитать уникальное количество emp_id

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) AS qty FROM org
GROUP BY name
```

Вторая интерпретация, подсчитать так, что бы исключить `emp_id`  встречающиеся у разных `name`
Для этого пойдем от обратного
подсчитаем количество `name` у `emp_id`, то есть нам необходимо исключить из выборки  `emp_id` встречающиеся у нескольких `name`

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT emp_id) AS qty FROM org
    WHERE NOT emp_id IN
    (
       SELECT emp_id FROM org
       GROUP BY emp_id
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1 
    )
GROUP BY name
```

Унифицировать или нет дело ваше, смотря что там лежит и как

Comment: Хм... Проверил в работе. После того, как за этот ответ проголосовали, еще раз проверил, но [результат выдаёт не правильный](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afac1/21/0). Ничего не имею против, но что-то тут не так.

Comment: Почему же не правильный:
Петя 5, 100
Вася 15, 20
Итого по два на каждого))

Comment: Для второй интерпретации так и есть потому что 30, 10 и 1 в встречаются и у Васи и у Пети, если смотреть на ваш пример)

Comment: @ЫЫЫ ваша первая интерпретация практически то, что мне надо. Но есть сложности, которые я дописал в вопросе

Comment: А какие проблемы? Запрос первой интерпретации и дает желаемый результат

Comment: Да, вы правы. Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT `emp_id` FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `emp_id` HAVING COUNT(`emp_id`) = 1
```

**UPD**

Как-то всё уж очень мудрёно у всех получается. )) Если надо сравнивать не только значение поля *emp_id*, но и соответствующее ему поле *name*, то почему бы их не объединить?

```
SELECT `emp_id`, CONCAT(`name`,`emp_id`) AS uv FROM `uniq` GROUP BY uv HAVING COUNT(uv) = 1
```

Вот что мы получим в итоге: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afac1/1

Всё, что теперь остается сделать, так это высчитать количество уникальных записей и сгруппировать по полю *name*. Итоговый запрос:

```
SELECT t1.`name`,COUNT(t1.`emp_id`) AS cnt
FROM `uniq` t1 
  WHERE CONCAT(t1.`name`,t1.`emp_id`) IN (
    SELECT CONCAT(t2.`name`,t2.`emp_id`) AS uv 
    FROM `uniq` t2 
    GROUP BY uv HAVING COUNT(uv) = 1
)
GROUP BY t1.`name`
```

Желающим посмотреть в действии - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afac1/14/0 
Вот как бы и всё ))

Comment: А если разные name имеют одинаковые emp_id ?

Comment: @mikillskegg, задача состоит в том, чтоб найти **уникальные значения** в поле **`emp_id`**? Или я что-то пропустил?

Comment: >Для каждого возможного значения name, необходимо вывести количество уникальных emp_id.

Answer (score 1):

`group by name` может быть? А дальше их `distinct`

**update 1**

ok, см сюда [Mysql: Select unique values ​​within the group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746695/mysql-select-unique-values-within-the-group)

Ну в любом случае, будут вложенные запросы.

**update 2**

```
select t1, count(t2) as t4 from (

select 
    substring(new1,0,charindex('/',new1)) as t1, 
    substring(new1,charindex('/',new1)+1,len(new1)) as t2, 
    new1 from 

(select distinct name + '/' + emp_id as new1 from org) temp1
) temp2

group by t1
```

Comment: distinct просто уберет повторы и "стянет" повторяющиеся в одно. Т.е. count вернет общее число видов значений

Comment: тут без вложенного запроса быть не может, т.к. сначала нужно их "уникализировать" что-то типа from (select distinct name+'/'+ emp_id as tmp from org) а из этого делать group by и вести подсчет

Comment: Поделитесь кодом, если нетрудно.

Comment: поделился, времени больше нет, если катит, то палец вверх :)

Answer (score 1):

Йоксель!

```
select name, count(distinct emp_id)
from my_temp
group by name
;
```